# Durandal : view and viewModel still persists in heap memory

Tags: knockout.js, durandal, single-page-application

I am working on big SPA project with `durandal` and `knockout`.

We are facing memory leak issue.

Normally we are in one page and we need to go to next page .

Browser heap get cleared while we go to next page and vice versa.

In our SPA while routing we need to clear current page hap size (Memory) .

Is there any way in `durandal` compose binding ?.

Comment: How does your ViewModel look like, activate and deactive functions? If you your require function returns a ctor durandal should create a new instance each time

Comment: Does your viewmodel re-instantiate when you change views?

Comment: Deactivate was already mentioned. You could release any memory eating stuff there when navigating to another page

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- HTML Page Templates -->

    <article class="main-user-page">
        <div data-bind="compose: {model: '/viewmodel/viewLoginUser',view:'view/viewLoginUser'}">

        </div>
    </article >

    <article class="main-user-list-page">
        <div data-bind="compose: {model: '/viewmodel/user/viewUserList',view:'view/user/viewUserList'}">

        </div>
    </article >

    <article class="user-list-page">
        <div data-bind="forEach: userList">
            <span data-bind="Name"></span>
            <span data-bind="email"></span>
            <span data-bind="Role"></span>
        </div>
    </article >
<code>
<pre>
/*we are using Durandal for routing and composeing template 
  all files have same Structure 
*/
function define(['services/utilities', 'durandal/app', 'durandal/system', 'services/logger', 'config', 'services/datacontext','services/bindingHandler'],
    function (util, app, system, logger, config, datacontext) {
    var userList = ko.observableArray([]);

    var userObj = ko.observable();
    function activate(){
        return datacontext.getUserList().then(result){
            userList(result);
        }
    }
    function deactivate(){
        userList.removeAll();
    }
    return {
        userList: userList,
        userObj: userObj
    }
});

</pre>

</code>
```

Comment: did this work for you? do you have to always clear out knockout bindings in the deactivate?